# SOAP Compression Options returning error

Tags: php, soap

I am adding a compression option to my SOAPClient in PHP5 and I receive this message.

Why? I've seen many examples using the exact same syntax.

```
'compression' =>    SOAP_COMPRESSION_ACCEPT | SOAP_COMPRESSION_GZIP | 5
```

returns:

```
Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '|', expecting ')' in /home/absolute/public_html/book/bin/class/wsdl.class.php on line 5042
```

The options Array

```
$options = array( 'cache_wsdl' => 0,'trace' => 1,'encoding' => 'utf-8','soap_version' =>    SOAP_1_2,'compression' => SOAP_COMPRESSION_ACCEPT | SOAP_COMPRESSION_GZIP | 5 )


public function WEBService($wsdl = "x.x.x.x/Service.asmx?wsdl", $options = array( 'cache_wsdl' => 0,
'trace' => 1, 
'encoding' =>'utf-8',
'soap_version' =>   SOAP_1_2,
'compression' =>    SOAP_COMPRESSION_ACCEPT | SOAP_COMPRESSION_GZIP | 5 )) 
{
      // some class mapping and other wonderful things going on
}
```

Comment: Can you show us some context, please?

Comment: we'd need the rest of the array in which the `compression` key is defined -- the syntax error could be the result of a previous line, for example.

Comment: @Charles - I have added the options array to the Question. THanks

Answer (score 4):

The problem has nothing to do with SOAP. Witness the same error with this reduced test case:

```
function foo($x = 1 | 2) {}
```

Quoth [the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default):

> The default value must be a constant expression, not (for example) a variable, a class member or a function call.

While `SOAP_COMPRESSION_ACCEPT | SOAP_COMPRESSION_GZIP | 5` could effectively be a constant at "compile" time, PHP apparently doesn't do such constant collapsing and therefore chokes on the non-constant expression.

You certainly have seen such code before, just not as the default value of a function argument. A simple way around it would be to default the arg to `false` or `null`, and then in the body of the function test for that and assign the desired value.

Comment: In the PHP Manual for defining SOAP Compression options, it is coded as `SOAP_COMPRESSION_ACCEPT | SOAP_COMPRESSION_GZIP` [PHP SOAP MANUAL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php)

Comment: @claw: And there it is *not* in the default value of a function argument.

Answer (score 0):

You just need brackets:

```
'compression' =>    (SOAP_COMPRESSION_ACCEPT | SOAP_COMPRESSION_GZIP | 5)
```

Due to operator precedence.